# SQL Store number of rows in a table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to know if it is possible to run a SQL query which returns the number of rows round in a table. I have a page which upon clicked, it will run sql queries which compares data between 2 tables, thus I will want the user to be notified if one or more table is empty.

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATASOURCE");

    SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

    try
    {
        thisConnection.Open();
        //sql statement to check if a table is empty
        //stores the count value in a integer X

        if( X < 1 )
        {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Database X is empty');</script>");
            return;
        }
     }
```

Qs: Do I use `Select Count(*) from Table` to retrieve the number of rows in a table?

How do I store the Count (*) value into an Integer?

Thank you in advance.

---

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Instead of checking for count, you could check for if the table has atleast 1 row using `TOP 1`. Isn't it?

Comment: TOP 1 is very server specific. That won't work on Oracle, DB2, MySql. The OP hasn't mentioned his db vendor yet.

Comment: Hi shahkalpesh, I guess the statement will be SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table. But how do make a check afterwards that it is not empty or null?

Comment: Count(*) returns a single integer instead of, potentially, a whole row of data.  What do I want all that other data for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public int CountRowsInTable()
{
   string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTable";
   int count = 0;

   using(SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATASOURCE"))
   using(SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(stmt, thisConnection))
   {
       thisConnection.Open();
       count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
       thisConnection.Close();
   }

   return count;
}
```

Again: this works and gives you an accurate count - but it can be very very slow on large tables.

Alternatives:

- peek into the system catalog views to get an *approximate* count (not accurate - but fast)
- don't count - but just make sure you have at least one row (using `SELECT TOP 1....` and making sure you get *something* back)

**Update:** to simply check whether a table contains **any rows** at all, you could use this `TOP 1` approach which should be really fast - even for large tables:

```
public bool TableContainsAnyRows()
{
   // define a TOP 1 query - typically by the Primary Key of the table in question
   // using AdventureWorks sample database here
   string stmt = "SELECT TOP 1 [BusinessEntityID] FROM Person.Person ORDER BY [BusinessEntityID]";

   bool containsAnyRows = false;

   // open a connection and execute this query against the database 
   using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=AdventureWorks2008R2;integrated Security=SSPI;"))
   using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, _con))
   {
       _con.Open();

       // getting the result of the query
       // if the table contains *any* rows, the result will *NOT* be NULL
       object result = _cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       _con.Close();

       containsAnyRows = (result != null);
   }

   return containsAnyRows;
}
```

Comment: How can i store the query by using `TOP 1` into a variable and check if it is not null?

Comment: @RUiHAO: updated my response with an example of a `TOP 1` query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable;
```

Afterwards retrieve the first row from your result.

Comment: How do I store the count value as an Integer?

Comment: This depends on your programming language. I can only see that you are not using Java and I don't like to guess.

Comment: Works - but on large tables (> 100 mio. rows) this end up being very very slow.....

Comment: @marc_s He says he's concerned that the tables are empty... I kinda doubt millions of rows are going to be an issue then :)